# Градиент Shader Graph URP 2d sprite из белого в прозрачный

Tags: unity3d, linear-gradient, shader-graph

Как сделать градиент который плавно переходит из белого в прозрачный, мне нужно для 2D спрайта через shader graph URP. Я уже вроде бы настроил и всё должно работать, но почему-то спрайт из белого переходит в чёрный, а не в прозрачный. Почему такое может происходить?

[Ноды Shader Graph](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S2ujMkqJ0r9ZB50QVB6OcBTEBp1BXzRZ/view?usp=drive_link)

[Неверно отображаемый спрайт](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xd9SMzaubjaQzG7mazYIkVvuuDkmdzJn/view?usp=drive_link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял, что я неправильно сделал graph. Я записал туториал для Ютуб как правильно сделать прозрачный градиент для Юнити. Вот ссылка:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKp1sWAEMUg&t=604s

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)